# Problem with python, POO, tkinter and save problems

Tags: python, class, tkinter, textbox, traceback

This is the code, I hope someone could help me please.
I created a class and an object. I want to use a textbox to enter a property of the object. After that i want to use a button to show the property in the window.

```
from tkinter import *

add_window = Tk()
add_window.resizable(False, True)
add_window.geometry("300x400")
add_window.title("Add a new account")
add_window.configure(bg="Black")


class cuenta:
     app_web = StringVar()


def com(self):
    c = self.app_web.get()
    titulo = Label(text=c, font=20).grid(row=3, column=1)

cuenta1 = cuenta()

app_web = Label(add_window, text="App or web: ", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Segoe UI", 12))
app_web.grid(row=1, column=0)
caja_app = Entry(add_window, textvariable=cuenta1.app_web, bg="grey88", fg="black").grid(row=1, column=1)
boton_save = Button(add_window, text="Save", command=cuenta.com(cuenta1), bg="azure4", 
fg="white").grid(row=2, column=1)

add_window.mainloop()
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\offcampus\Desktop\bahula.py", line 23, in 
>       boton_save = Button(add_window, text="Save", command=cuenta.com(cuenta1), bg="azure4", 
>   AttributeError: type object 'cuenta' has no attribute 'com'
>   [Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
>   [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\offcampus\Desktop\bahula.py"]
>   [dir: C:\Users\offcampus\Desktop]
>   [path: C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\offcampus\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\offcampus\AppData\Local\Programs\python35\paint.py;C:\Users\offcampus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35;C:\Users\offcampus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python;]

Comment: Here the error that I have:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dilan/PycharmProjects/Udemy/Agenda 2.0/Tets.py", line 23, in <module>
    boton_save = Button(add_window, text="Save", command=cuenta.com(cuenta1), bg="azure4", fg="white").grid(row=2, column=1)
AttributeError: type object 'cuenta' has no attribute 'com'

Comment: You probably just need to indent that `com` method (add 4 spaces on the left)

Comment: What's your question? You've told us what you want but haven't explained what's preventing you from doing it. What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Bryan Oakley the question is "Why did I have Traceback error?", I didn't know that I have to define my funtions inside the class  [1 week rookie error learning]  (Thank you Remram!!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you need to define the `com` function inside the class `cuenta`. Instead you defined it outside the class. You need to indent the function in by four spaces.

Here is the code:

```py
from tkinter import *

add_window = Tk()
add_window.resizable(False, True)
add_window.geometry("300x400")
add_window.title("Add a new account")
add_window.configure(bg="Black")


class cuenta:
    app_web = StringVar()
    def com(self):
        c = self.app_web.get()
        titulo = Label(text=c, font=20).grid(row=3, column=1)

cuenta1 = cuenta()

app_web = Label(add_window, text="App or web: ", bg="black", fg="white", font=("Segoe UI", 12))
app_web.grid(row=1, column=0)
caja_app = Entry(add_window, textvariable=cuenta1.app_web, bg="grey88", fg="black").grid(row=1, column=1)
boton_save = Button(add_window, text="Save", command=cuenta.com(cuenta1), bg="azure4", 
fg="white").grid(row=2, column=1)

add_window.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!